# Authentication in a SharePoint environment

Tags: sharepoint, windows-authentication

We are developing a Intranet portal that uses integrated authentication, but a few sections of the site will be exposed to users who are not in the domain. For those users we plan to use anonymous access. However, our display logic for the entire application is based on the user logged into the portal, so we are not fully comfortable with this approach. The URL has to be same for both types of users and transitioning between both the environments has to be seamless.

We tried using user controls in pages to authenticate but things didnt pan out. When the page is reached the standard windows authentication grey box pops up.

Is there any way to intercept the request at the IIS level like an HTTP application?
If applicable we would disable anonymous access and for unauthenticated users we will impersonate with a least privileged domain account and redirect to the home page.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint isn't really designed for the scenario you describe of mixing types of authentication. It dedicates a web application to **one type of authentication**. You can then 'extend' that web application to use another type of authentication on another address. For example, your intranet portal would use Windows authentication. It could then be extended to use anonymous authentication on another port or domain name.

One option for what you describe is to configure two separate web applications. One is for users that need to authenticate. The other is for anonymous access. Configure the content in the appropriate locations and link between the two as necessary. Users within your domain should not receive a login prompt when connecting to the authenticated site if you use this approach. Users outside your domain will receive a login box and won't be able to access.

**Consider using forms authentication for users outside your domain** if they need to access your intranet. (Once again the 'forms authenticated' part of your site would be extended to a unique domain name or port.) This would mean they will be prompted to enter their credentials in a form on the page when first connecting.

Read more about authentication on the [**Authentication Resource Center**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sharepointserver/bb735938.aspx).

A couple of final points... If you can use SharePoint's default authentication mechanisms rather than writing your own controls, use them as they are well tested and secure. Also, **don't be tempted to change SharePoint's IIS settings** unless you are certain there is no other way to do what you need. SharePoint regularly updates these itself and may overwrite your changes (or give you grief in other ways).